# How to solve this ThrowableProxy exception on spring

Tags: spring, gradle, logback

I have spring (gradle) application: spring version 1.5.2 and 2 java jar modules.

when I deployed on the server (amazon ami Linux) all is ok, but after ~2  minutes throw this exception

```
Exception in thread "http-nio-8585-exec-7" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Exception in thread "http-nio-8585-exec-7" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/ThrowableProxy
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Logger.java:765)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:1042)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:181)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.error(DirectJDKLog.java:147)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1451)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How to solve this problem. 
Thanks.

Comment: Problem is solved!!!

Comment: how do you solved this?